# webread function doesn't work for reading JSON in Matlab 2016b

Tags: json, matlab, web

I am running

```
>> webread(url)
Error using webread (line 116)
Too many input arguments.
```

`url` is just URL returning JSON.

**UPDATE**

```
>> webread('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
116 [url, postData, options] = encodeInputs(url, queryParams, options);
Error using webread (line 116)
Too many input arguments.

>> ver
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB Version: 9.1.0.441655 (R2016b)
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Version 10.0 (Build 16299)
Java Version: Java 1.8.0_111-b14 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB                                                Version 9.1         (R2016b)
....
```

**UPDATE 2**

Content of the function:

```
function varargout = webread(url, varargin)
...
% Parse the inputs.
[queryParams, options] = parseInputs(mfilename, varargin);

% Encode inputs.
[url, postData, options] = encodeInputs(url, queryParams, options);
```

line 116 is last one.

Path is `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\toolbox\matlab\external\interfaces\webservices\restful\webread.m`

**UPDATE 3**

Tracing shows root cause is in line #427 in `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\toolbox\matlab\external\interfaces\webservices\http\+matlab\+net\URI.m` which says:

```
obj.Path = strsplit(string(value), '/', 'CollapseDelimiters', false);
```

and

```
K>> strsplit(string(value), '/', 'CollapseDelimiters', false)
Error using strsplit
Too many input arguments.

K>> value

value = 

  string

    "/users"
```

and `strsplit` is my function which overrides build-in one!

Comment: It works for me with the test example from  `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`. Is your webpage RESTful?

Comment: @NickyMattsson you page doesn't work for me too

Comment: What is the content of your `webread` function?

Comment: @NickyMattsson see my update please

Comment: Am I right assuming you have solved the problem? If so, one tip is that whenever I create a new function, I always create it with `edit *name*` because if it already exists in the filepath, then it will just open, thus I know for sure I am not overwriting an existing function.